# Set the x and y position of canvas renderer

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Three.js make it easy to manage the width and height of the canvas renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( 500, 300 );
```

But still can not find a way to set the x and y of that object, i don't want to play it starting by the index (0,0), i look on the `CanvasRenderer.js` class but i didn't get a solution. Is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question or not, but the canvas can be moved around the page just like any other DOM element.

So you could do something like this:

```
renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
renderer.domElement.style.left = '100px';
```

You can also do this via a CSS file.